# What is the underlying concept in case of finding pressure inside a balloon kept at some height in atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, kinetic-theory

If we have a balloon containing air at sea level. Is the value of absolute pressure inside the balloon  decided by the temperature of the enclosed air or by the height of atmospheric column above it or by both. Or in other words should we use concepts of kinetic theory of gases only or concept of hydrostatics only or both concepts have to be used to answer this.

Comment: How could it not be a combination of the two? Wouldn't the only other option be that one of those factors had no bearing?

Answer (score 6):

If the volume of the balloon is not changing then the net force acting on any part of its shell is zero. If we neglect the forces applied upon the part of the shell by the nearby shell parts (the elastic tension of the shell), then it means that the pressure from the outside is equal to the pressure from the inside. In this case the pressure inside the balloon is determined by the height of atmospheric column above it. However, if the elastic tension of the shell is important, then the situation is different.

The elastic pressure of the shell depends on the radius of the balloon and its temperature. The radius of the balloon with the hot air inside will be larger. Thus, if you take the elastic tension in the shell into account then the pressure of the gas inside the balloon will be determined both by the hydrostatics and the kinetic theory of gases, as well as elastic properties of the shell.

Comment: But when we look into the equation for how atmospheric pressure  varies with height , there all g, h, T and molecular mass  play part. And at the same time the walls of baloon  being at rest means pressure  inside is equal to pressure outside plus elastic factors. So pressure inside has to vary with pressure outside and outside pressure depends on the already stated factors out of which some play part in kinetic theory and some in hydrostatics

Answer (score 3):

Both.  If the balloon is inflated, then, neglecting the small pressure difference between inside and outside due to tension in the elastic balloon membrane, the pressure of the gas inside the balloon must match the pressure outside the balloon caused by the weight of the atmospheric air column.